# Correct JSDoc signature for is_string function?

Tags: jsdoc

I have the following function of type `(obj:any)=>boolean` that determines whether an object is string or not.
I want the JsDoc to be "smart" so that whenever I use `if(isString(x)){ ...block... }`, the highlighter treats `x` inside the block as a string.

So far I tried this without success:

```js
/** @type {((obj:string)=>true)|((obj:any)=>false)} */
function isString(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object String]";
}
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick. It uses the [Typescript's narrowing with type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```js
/** @type {(obj: any) => obj is String} */
function isString(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object String]";
}
```